# "Error: Error decoding signature" and "Variable '$token' is never used in operation 'VerifyToken'."

Tags: django, graphql, next.js, django-graphql-jwt

**Tools**:
Django + Next.js + Django-GraphQL-JWT

**What works**:
I can login the user and obtain a JWT token, which I save in addition to saving the token in the localStorage to retrieve and verify later.

**What does not work**:
I can successfully retrieve the localStorage token, but when I try to use the library to verify the token on the server, I get this error:

`[GraphQL error]: Message: Error decoding signature, Location: [object Object], Path: verifyToken`

Verification code:

```
const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(null);
const [localToken, setLocalToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  }, []);

...
const verifyToken = async () => {
    const client = createApolloClient();
    const data = await client.mutate({
      mutation: verifyMutation,
      variables: { token: localToken },
    });
    if (data) {
      setAuthToken(data.data.tokenAuth.token);
    }
    return data;
  };
...
```

Mutation:

```
export const verifyMutation = gql`
  mutation VerifyToken($token: String!) {
    verifyToken(token: $token) {
      payload
    }
  }
`;
```

schema.py:

```
class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()
    revoke_token = graphql_jwt.Revoke.Field()
```

Here is what happens when I try this manually in GraphQL:

If my mutation includes the token:

```
mutation VerifyToken($token: String!) {
  verifyToken(token: "token_string_here") {
    payload
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$token' is never used in operation 'VerifyToken'.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 22
        }
      ],
      "path": null
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if I do not include the token as such:

```
mutation VerifyToken {
  verifyToken {
    payload
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "verifyToken": {
      "payload": {
        "username": "myname",
        "exp": 1623076467,
        "origIat": 1623076167
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Other things I have tried**:
I have found some reference to SECRET_KEY being an issue with decoding but I have set it in my settings without any improvement in the problem. I have not found any other solutions that would seem to work here.

I have also tried using a custom JWT_VERIFY module but this did not help me fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, ok then. So the login portion wasn't working for me initially until I used this code taken from another tutorial:

`localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(data.data.tokenAuth.token));`

I didn't realize that the token was being set with a different format and thus does not match what the token looks like in the JWT.

Changing the code to the following this solved the issue! Hope this helps someone else:

`localStorage.setItem("token", data.data.tokenAuth.token);`